# POSTGRESQL: Connect remote server to host database with Python

Tags: python, sockets, postgresql, psycopg2

Using Python/Psycopg2/PopstgreSQL and Cron.
I'd like to take remote server information(see below) and add it into a PostGreSQL database on the host computer.

```
    Using #!/usr/bin/python 
import socket 
import commands 
import string 
import os 
hostname = socket.gethostname() 
print hostname 
ip = commands.getoutput("ifconfig").split("\n")[1].split()[1][5:] 
print ip 
os = commands.getoutput("lsb_release -d") 
print os[13:34] 
kernel = commands.getoutput("uname -p") 
print kernel 
reboot = commands.getoutput("who -b") 
print reboot[22:38]
```

This is the 'connect to database' script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import psycopg2
import sys

try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect('host=*** dbname=*** user=*** password=***')
        print "Connected to Database"
except:
        print "No Connection"

cur = conn.cursor()#cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
try:
        cur.execute('SELECT * FROM new')
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        print "\n Show: \n"
        for row in rows:
                print "   ", row
except:
        print "Not Working"
```

I'm able to connect, I'm able to pull the data.  I need to combine the two scripts and insert the returned information into the database.

Answer (score 2):

Your local python script would have these lines:

```
import psycopg2 as db
remote_connection = db.connect('host=that_host dbname=that_db user=user password=pwd')
local_connection = db.connect('host=localhost dbname=local_db user=user password=pwd')
```

Comment: Thank you.  After connecting to the database from a remote machine... how would I go about taking information(commands.getouput("uptime")) and take the result and place that into a column?

Comment: Your questions are too broad. The format of this site is for very specific questions. You need to research first and only then make your questions.